# Can't connect to MySQL server. Keeps changing the host IP to a local IP

Tags: networking, windows-10, mysql

I've encountered an odd problem and I'm unsure what is causing it as it has been completely fine prior to today.

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL Server but it is changing the IP address to another address that represents my local IP.

**Example**

*(I've replaced the IPs and domains for obvious reasons)*

I'm trying to connect to:

```
43.124.65.13:3306
```

But connection is replacing it to:

```
 host-12-382-224-82.as12265.net
```

as shown on the error that is returned back to me.

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'host-12-382-224-82.as12265.net'`

The IP **12.382.224.82** is my own network IP from whatsmyip.org and googling as12265.net leads to multiple logs referring to Talk-Talk which is my ISP.

Any idea what could be causing this? I've tried disabling the firewall, windows defender, and malwarebytes premium but it is still happening. I can connect to the MySQL server fine on other devices too so it's just this one.

I have just tried connecting via proxy and now it is changing the IP to the same one as the proxy I'm connected to. Perhaps this is a MySQL setting?

Windows 10

MySQL 5.7.26

Comment: I'm guessing here, but can you restart your mysql server using the [`--skip-name-resolve`](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.5/en/dns.html) option? Perhaps then it will not try to resolve the IP to a hostname?